# React: MUI v5 button not updating after refreshing the page in the built site

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using MUI v5 with react and Gatsby and, everything works perfectly fine in development, except when I reload the page in the built version.

I have this button that should be disabled if there are no items in a list, but if there are items it should not be disabled.

Everything works fine as long as I don't refresh the page. I can add, remove and edit items in the list and the button gets enabled/disabled accordingly.

The problem is, if I have items in the list (not disabled) and I refresh the page, the button gets disabled, even though I have items in the list. I've tried printing the number of items in the button's text and it effectively shows the correct number.

This is my button:

```
const CustomButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  color: theme.palette.greyscale.black,
  '&:hover, &:active, &:focus': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    opacity: 0.85,
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
    fontSize: '12px',
    lineHeight: '20px',
    paddingTop: '8px',
    paddingBottom: '8px',
  },
}));
```

And this is how I use it:

```
...
        <CustomButton
          variant="primary"
          onClick={blah}
          disabled={list.length < 1}
        >
           GOTO BLAH - {list.length}
        </CustomButton>
...
```

Comment: Where is the value of the list variable coming from and are you doing SSR on the components?

Comment: Turns out it was a hydration problem when doing SSR with Gatsby and looks like this is a very hard to debug known issue, here's a link to its discussion on Github: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/17914